# URL redirect using PHP or Apache rewrite

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to achieve the following:

If a given URL is:
    http://example.com/abcdef

then, the web app should understand it as:
    http://example.com/index.php?id=abcdef

BTW...i am a PHP and Apache beginner. What would be my best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It matches URLs using [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), so you should look into [some tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/you-dont-know-anything-about-regular-expressions/) on that if you want to rewrite your own URLs. There are also [plenty](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) [of](http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/) [tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/) [on](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html) [basic](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) [URL](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) [rewriting](http://edrackham.com/apache/beginners-mod_rewrite-tutorial/) [too](http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what if I have something like this...'example.com/dir/abcdef'? Would I have to place the .htaccess file in the 'example.com/dir' folder then?

Comment: You have two options. You can move the .htaccess file and index.php to the dir directory OR you can modify the rule a bit: `RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1`

Comment: @user21471 Which did you try? What is the definition of not working?

Comment: i tried both. but they didn't work. is this something to do with "mod_rewrite"?

Comment: @user21471 Ok so for moving the htaccess did you move both the htaccess and the index.php file into the directory?

Comment: yes. I put both 'index.php' and '.htacess' in the same directory, which in this case is "dir". Also, I noticed something new. The application now cannot find my style sheet. Changing ".htaccess" must have caused this. The style sheet is in "css" folder which is under the root (which is "dir"). The stylesheet location is "dir/css/style.css". Can you please comment on this?

Comment: You need to change your link to your CSS file to be absolute: `/dir/css/style.css`

Comment: Thanks for the insight. does this apply to any other/all files (e.g. javascript, css etc) that are included in the PHP file?

Comment: @user21471 Yep. As a rule of thumb, you should keep all assets (that's js, css, images, etc.) in directories in the web root. This way you can access them all with absolute URLs: `/css`, `/js`, `/images`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tried to do this-

> Options -MultiViews
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L]